# Date arithmetic not working properly in macos bash

Tags: macos, date, bsd

I am trying to subtract 5 minutes from date but its giving unexpected output.

```
$ date -j -f "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%s"  -v "-5M" "2021/03/01 09:11:14"
Thu Jan  1 05:25:14 IST 1970
```

Please suggest the correction.

Comment: `date -j -f "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S" -v "-5M" "2021/03/01 09:11:14"` should work for you. If you need UTC date-time then prefix this command with `TZ=UTC`

Comment: `%s` is seconds since the epoch, `%S` is the seconds part of the time.

Comment: @anubhava If you could post your solution as an answer, then I can accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

This date command should work on `BSD` date:

```sh
date -j -f "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S" -v "-5M" "2021/03/01 09:11:14"
```

Issue in your command was use of `.%s` instead of `.%S` for the second component.